# Swiper autoplay. Остановка при наведение курсора мыши на слайдер и запуск при отведение курсора

Tags: javascript, html, html5, swiper

Подскажите пожалуйста, слайдер перелистывает слайды при нажатии на кнопки и работает autoplay, но не останавливается когда курсор мыши наведен на конкретный слайд. В чём может быть ошибка?

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  spaceBetween: 30,
  speed: 400,
  centeredSlides: true,
  loop:true,
  autoplay: {
    delay: 1000,
    disableOnInteraction: true,
  },
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },


$('.swiper-container').on('mouseenter', function(){
  console.log('stop autoplay');
  swiper.stopAutoplay();
})
$('.swiper-container').on('mouseleave', function(){
   console.log('start autoplay');
   swiper.startAutoplay();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вот это. У меня работает.

```
$('.swiper-container').on('mouseenter', function (e) {
     swiper.autoplay.stop();
 })
 $('.swiper-container').on('mouseleave', function (e) {
     swiper.autoplay.start();
 })
```